# Правильность импртов PyQt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Какие из ниже перечисленных импортов являются более правильными по скорости и по читаемости.

**1 вариант**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Io(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        b = QCommandLinkButton("Переход")
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(b)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Io()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**2 вариант**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class Io(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        b = QtWidgets.QCommandLinkButton("Переход")
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(b)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Io()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**3 вариант**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QCommandLinkButton


class Io(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        b = QCommandLinkButton("Переход")
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(b)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Io()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: По скорости разницы нет, использовать стоит 2 или 3 варианты.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Есть замечательное правило, действующее во многих командах "Заимпортил звёздочку - получил по мордочке". А выбор между вторым и третьим вариантом - пожалуй, дело вкуса.

Comment: Кроме вкуса во 2 и 3 варианте можно ещё ориентироваться на банальное удобство. Если нужно из модуля всего два-три имени, то лучше явно их сразу указать в строке импорта. А если нужна целая дюжина, и сами имена не очень ясные, то лучше импортировать просто модуль, а потом от него через точку имена вызывать.

Answer (score 7):

Если вы хотите все qt имена в одном пространство имён импортировать, можно [Qt](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/Qt.html#PyQt5-Qt) использовать:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt
```

Это позволяет писать: `Qt.QApplication`, `Qt.QPoint`, `Qt.QPainter`, etc. Недостаток, что все qt модули импортируются, увеличивая время загрузки и потребляемую память, если фактически вам нужны только отдельные модули.

Не используйте `from module import *` за исключением специальных случаев: в REPL или в `__init__.py` файле. Пример оправданного использования: [`asyncio/__init__.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f9c682b2b3d6b2a87d60da51d857fdb4a1db89f5/Lib/asyncio/__init__.py)—`asyncio` предоставляет "плоский" публичный интерфейс (имена доступны прямо как `asyncio.name`), не смотря на то что реализация распределена по многочисленным вложенным модулям. Можно ли отнести импорты pyqt к специальным случаям, зависит могут ли конфликтующие имена появиться сегодня и в будущем (если все имена в `__all__` начинаются с `Q*`, то нет опасности, что вы их перепутаете со своими). Не применяйте правила вслепую, используйте голову [PEP-8:  "A Foolish Consistency is the Hobgoblin of Little Minds."](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds)