# Как выполнять математические действия с числами из поля ввода Entry (Tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Это отрывок кода, просто написал чтоб было как главное окно, вот мне очень нужно понять, как при вводе значений в Entry присваивать их переменным а потом выполнять математические операции?? я весь день сидел сегодня, ничего не получилось.

```
from tkinter import *


window3 = Tk()
window3.title('3. Найти Sn, b1')
window3.geometry('360x275')
window3.resizable(False, False)

label_b1_3 = Label(window3, text='Известный член прогрессии: ')
label_b1_3.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='wn', ipadx=1, ipady=2)

b1_3 = Entry(window3, text='', textvariable=info_b1_3)
b1_3.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='wn', ipadx=1, ipady=2)

label_n1_3 = Label(window3, text='Его номер в прогрессии: ')
label_n1_3.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='wn', ipadx=1, ipady=2)

n1_3 = Entry(window3, text='', textvariable=info_n1_3)
n1_3.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky='wn', ipadx=1, ipady=2)

label_q1_3 = Label(window3, text='Знаменатель прогрессии: ')
label_q1_3.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='wn', ipadx=1, ipady=2)

q1_3 = Entry(window3, text='', textvariable=info_q1_3)
q1_3.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky='wn', ipadx=1, ipady=2)

btn_get_info_window3 = Button(window3, text='Посчитать!', fg='red', font='11')
btn_get_info_window3.grid(row=6, column=2, sticky='n', ipadx=10, ipady=10)

def get_info_b1_3():
    info_b1_3.get()


def get_info_n1_3():
    info_n1_3.get()


def get_info_q1_3():
    info_n1_3.get()


info_b1_3 = StringVar()
info_n1_3 = StringVar()
info_q1_3 = StringVar()

window3.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вам пример функция сложения 2х переменных

```
import tkinter as tk


def func():
    try:
        x = float(entry_1.get())
        y = float(entry_2.get())
        label.config(text="Сумма числе будет равна {}".format(x + y))
    except ValueError:
        label.config(text="Ошибка введите цифры")


root = tk.Tk()
entry_1 = tk.Entry(root)
entry_2 = tk.Entry(root)
entry_1.pack()
entry_2.pack()
label = tk.Label(root, text="Сумма числе будет равна")
label.pack()
button = tk.Button(root, text='сложить числа', command=func)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое) А что можно сделать, чтоб при открытом дочернем окне нельзя было взаимодействовать с главным? И еще меня очень путает tk.Button, tk.Entry. Можно же просто импортировать все * и не писать tk

Comment: @АлександрБоканов По поводу `tk.Entry` и т.д. можете почитать тут [Правильность импртов PyQt](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/776848/255866) ( в принципе схожий вопрос), а по поводу дочернего окна лучше задать отдельный вопрос

Comment: Как я понял импорт * потом выдаст много ошибок неиспользованного импорта? или нет? я просто недавно начал изучать python

Comment: @АлександрБоканов: нагрузки на приложение дополнительной нет (импортируется модуль только целиком в любом случае). Есть нагрузка на программиста, читающего код: может быть неясно откуда имена берутся и есть ли конфликты имён сейчас или в *будущих версиях* (вы думаете имя из одного модуля, а оно из другого, к примеру: `tkinter` vs. `tkinter.ttk`)  -- не используйте `import *`, кроме [особых случаев](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/777053/23044)

Comment: @АлександрБоканов ответ на ваш первый комментарий: .grab_set()  запретить доступ к др. окнам, пока открыт диалог

Comment: [Как создать модальное окна](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/811405/255866)

Answer (score 1):

Можно просто через `eval("2+2")` оно будет думать что это не строка а мат. выражение и посчитает его

Comment: Для задачи, где нужно просто сложить значения двух полей, а не вычислить значение выражения в поле - это оверкилл. К тому же, eval не безопасен, поэтому в целом лучше его не использовать. Есть более безопасные альтернативы.