# Как сделать модальное окно в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Каким образом можно сделать виджет `TopLevel` модальным.
Пример для создания обычного окна через кнопку

```
from tkinter import Tk, Toplevel, Button, Label


def func():
    top = Toplevel(root)
    button_top_level = Button(top, text='Нажми', command=lambda: label.config(text='Текст из модального окна')).pack()


root = Tk()
label = Label(root, text='Текст')
label.pack()
button = Button(root, text='openModal', command=func).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: связанный вопрос [How to create a modal dialog in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16803686/4279)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При помощи функции `grab_set` мы передаем поток данному виджету т.е. делаем его модальным(нельзя переключиться на главное окно).

При помощи функции `focus_set()` мы фокусируем наше приложение на окне `top`, а при помощи функции `wait_window()` мы задаем приложению команду, что пока не будет закрыто окно `top` пользоваться другим окном будет нельзя.
При помощи `transient(root)` можно убарть кнопки свернуть/развернуть, а так же расширить экран благодаря чему получим простое модальное диалоговое окно.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Toplevel, Button, Label


def func():
    top = Toplevel(root)
    button_top_level = Button(top, text='Нажми', command=lambda: label.config(text='Текст из модального окна')).pack()
    top.transient(root)
    top.grab_set()
    top.focus_set()
    top.wait_window()


root = Tk()
label = Label(root, text='Текст')
label.pack()
button = Button(root, text='openModal', command=func).pack()
root.mainloop()
```